# custom actions to ribbon ui in infopath 2010 forms for sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath, custom-actions

I have created 4 custom actions at the item display ribbon using SPdesigner2013. It works fine.
However, when I customize the list form in InfoPath, these custom action buttons dissappear.
They are accessible only when I use the sharepoint default forms. (not for the customized infopath forms).

Could someone give me some ideas how to solve this issue

thanks in advance

P.S. please someone answer at least if it is a valid question or i am doing something wrong.

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this.  I have the exact same problem.

Comment: no i did not. it requires a lot of code i think. instead i placed buttons in the sharepoint form to trigger these workflows.